# Linux Mint KDE sha256sum not matching

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I've downloaded the Mint KDE iso from their website and via torrent. So far I've downloaded it four times, followed the verification instructions four times, and got four different sha256sums **none** of which match the one on their website!!

What's going on? Is my linux system corrupt? And **how can I tell**?

(I feel very vulnerable not having any sort of linux malware checker - supposing I had downloaded the corrupt Mint version earlier this year and not read the publicity, how could I have known? Could I have still been running a compromised system??)

Answer (score 0):

Early this year, the Mint download site was hacked, so they instituted a complicated verification procedure.  Unfortunately, it's a little problem prone.  If you want to follow their prescribed procedure, which is as close to bulletproof as you can get, they have the procedure listed [here](https://linuxmint.com/verify.php), which may be what you followed.  There is also a good tutorial here: http://www.howtogeek.com/246332/how-to-verify-a-downloaded-linux-iso-file-wasnt-tampered-with/.

However, the process is much more complicated than other distros use, mainly as a reaction to having been hacked.  The Mint people are now extremely vigilant about their repositories, and their new verification procedure discourages a repeat of the hacking.  So it's as safe as pretty much any other distro to simply  verify the hash manually.  If you want to be a little paranoid for good measure, just check back at the Mint site over the following day or two for a notice that they discovered a hack or to see if the ISO or hash changed.

If you're comfortable just manually comparing the hash values, you can look on the Release web page ([here's the one for the latest Mint KDE version](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3092)).  They include a link to the hash values ("link to the sums"), for the current version:

[image: hash links]

Right now, it points to this file: https://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/linuxmint.com/stable/18/sha256sum.txt, which shows these values for 32-bit and 64-bit versions:

[image: hash values]

I'm including these only as examples of what to look for, since the values will change with each update to the ISO.

To get the SHA256 value for your ISO, run this command in a terminal in Linux:

```
sha256sum /path/to/file.iso
```

If you are downloading the ISO from Windows, there are various utilities available to generate the hash value.  Here's a [link](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Burning_ISO_images_to_disc/sect-Burning_ISO_images_to_disc-Validating_the_Files-Validating_at_the_Windows_Command_Prompt.html) that describes getting and using a few choices, such as sha256sum.exe.

If you compare the published hash value to what you get running a hash calculator on the ISO, they should match.  Note that the chances of a random number matching are infinitesimal, so when you got a bunch of different results, if any one of them matched, you should be good.